# Como posso colocar caracteres no meio de uma string, sem sobrescreve-la em c?

Tags: c

Como posso colocar caracteres no meio de uma string, sem sobrescreve-la?

Preciso cada vez que encontrar um espaço, adicionar mais 3 espaços:

```
TESTE TESTE TESTE
```

E transformar pra isso:

```
TESTE   TESTE   TESTE
```

Tentei fazer assim, ele até adiciona os espaços, mas esta sobrescrevendo o resto da string...

Comment: Basicamente, vc precisa de 2 contadores: um pra posição da string `s` e outro pra posição da string `teste` (não pode usar o mesmo em `teste[i++]`, já que quando encontra um espaço, `i` deve andar apenas 1 casa, enquanto na string `teste` vc anda mais posições)

Comment: As respostas abaixo são complementares, uma diz pra usar `fgets` em vez de `gets` (correto, mas o resto da resposta vc pode ignorar porque não faz diferença - veja o comentário deixado lá), e a outra mostra como usar funções já existentes (`strtok`, etc), mas caso não possa usar essas funções (talvez seja um exercício que tenha essa restrição), a ideia de ter 2 contadores seria mais ou menos assim: https://ideone.com/G0n1b4 (ainda não é muito robusta porque vc deveria fazer uma conta pra alocar espaço suficiente - no pior caso, em que `s` só tem espaços, tem que alocar o triplo do tamanho)

Answer (score 2):

Uma possibilidade é utilizando as funções do arquivo de cabeçalho [string.h](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/) que define várias funções para manipular arrays de caracteres.
Use a função [`strtok()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) para dividir uma string em substring a cada ocorrência de um delimitador. Em uma primeira chamada, a função espera uma string C como argumento, cujo primeiro caractere é usado como local inicial para procurar delimitadores. Em chamadas subsequentes, a função espera um ponteiro nulo e usa a posição logo após o final do último delimitador como o novo local inicial para varredura.

Use a função [`strncat()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/) para juntar as substrings obtidas com `strtok()` mais os espaços:

> Esse código não faz a verificação de [buffer overrun](http://Transbordamento%20de%20dados).
> Esse código não testa entrada vazia.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] ="TESTE TESTE TESTE";                  //Declara string de entrada.
    char result[256];                                 //Declara uma porção de memória para conter o resultado.
    memset(result,'\0',256);                          //Prepara a memória que conterá o resultado.
    char * pstr = strtok(str, " ");                   //Quebra a entrada na primeira ocorrência do caractere espaço. 
    do
    {
      strncat(result, pstr, (unsigned)strlen(pstr));  //Adiciona ao resultado a  substring resultante da quebra da entrada.
      pstr = strtok (NULL, " ");                      //Quebra a entrada na próxima ocorrência do caractere espaço. 
      if (pstr == NULL) break;                        //Se não houver outra sbstring abandona o laço.
      strncat(result, "   ", 3);                      //Adiciona a três espaços ao resultado
    } while (true);
    printf ("%s\n",result);
    return 0;
}
//TESTE   TESTE   TESTE
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [ide.one](https://ideone.com/PMZ3ZA)</sup>

Answer (score -3):

o `gets` é uma função que está em desuso, já faz tempo,  melhor usar o `fgets`,

```
fgets(s , sizeof( s )  , stdin);
```

o finalizador de string é o valor zero  `0`,

```
for(int i=0; s[i]  !=0;  i++);
```

e não precisa das aspas nem da barra , coloque no final da string  teste , depois de preenchida

```
teste[w] = 0;
```

o loop for para colocar os espaços, esta indo ate enquanto for menor que 4  , e assim vai colocar Quatro e não Três espaços .

Comment: Na verdade, para terminar uma string, o `0` e `'\0'` [são equivalentes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462305) (apesar que o segundo deixa mais claro a intenção, que é usar um caractere, e não o valor numérico)